# SimpleMessageListenerContainer doesn't start on time

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

Unable to start SimpleMessageListenerContainer in reasonable amount of time. What could cause this problem?

The broker is up and running ok.

Container blocks on the method that is shown bellow.

[image]

The log is cycling for all created queues but it takes to long, the sample is provided below.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1a4339eb345eb0ce050

Spring AMQP v.1.4.4

Rabbit config is default (with several enabled plugins like x-consistent-hash)

And it worked pretty fast when we used on consumer per queue.

Comment: Please show configuration and Spring AMQP version. Run with DEBUG enabled for `org.springframework.amqp`; if you can't figure it out from the log, post the log someplace (e.g. Gist or pastebin - it's probably too big for here).

Comment: You need to show all of the log and all of the Spring Configuration.

Comment: Sorry, can't do this, right now.